# Translation program from VBA to vb NET

Tags: vb.net, vba, text, openfiledialog

Generally I have this working program as a macro in Excel and i wanted do extract it as a one button simple windows application. Is there a simple way to do this or better try to recognize differences between VBA and VB.Net and try to write it from scratch?

```
Sub Zapisywanie_txt_Biesse_WR()

    Dim TextFile As Integer
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileContent As String, strContent() As String
    Dim NewName As String
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim FileNum As String
    Dim Last_Dot As Long
    Dim posStart As Integer
    Dim posLength As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim LPX As Integer
    Dim MyTxtFile

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandle

    'Zmienic domyslna lokacje na lokacje aplikacji
    'ChDir "C:\Users\marcin.perz\Desktop\makro zmieniajace pliki"
    ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path

    'Spytac sie o plik do przerobienia
    FilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt),*.txt")

    'Nastepny wolny numer dla txt
    TextFile = FreeFile

    'Otworzenie txt w trybie odczytu
    Open FilePath For Input As TextFile

    'Zapisanie zawartosci pliku do pamieci
    FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)

    'Zamkniecie pliku
    Close TextFile

    'Znajdz/zamien prcedury
    FileContent = Replace(FileContent, "campoD0=LABL,A,4,4,NULL,0,0", "campoD0=LABL,A,4,4,NULL,0,0")
    FileContent = Replace(FileContent, "campoD1=PROG,A,256,8,NULL,0,2", "campoD1=PROG,A,256,8,NULL,0,2")
    FileContent = Replace(FileContent, "campoD2=QNTA,U,4,4,NULL,0,0", "campoD2=QNTA,U,4,4,NULL,0,0")
    FileContent = Replace(FileContent, "campoD3=CONT,U,4,4,NULL,0,0", "campoD3=CONT,U,4,4,NULL,0,0")
    FileContent = Replace(FileContent, "campoD4=COMM,A,768,80,NULL,0,0", "campoD4=COMM,A,768,80,NULL,0,0")
    FileContent = Replace(FileContent, "ORDRE", "$ ORDRE")
    FileContent = Replace(FileContent, "," & vbCrLf, " $, " & vbCrLf)

    'Nastepny wolny numer dla txt
    TextFile = FreeFile

    'Nadanie nowej nazwy lokazcji
    Last_Dot = InStrRev(FilePath, ".")
    NewName = Left$(FilePath, Last_Dot - 1) & "_rover35" & Mid$(FilePath, Last_Dot)
    FilePath = NewName

    'Otworzenie txt w trybie zapisu
    Open FilePath For Output As TextFile

    'Zapisanie zmienionej zawartosci do pliku
    Print #TextFile, FileContent

    'Zakmniecie pliku
    Close TextFile

    '~~> Podzielenie pliku na linie binarnie
    Open FilePath For Binary As #1
    FileContent = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , FileContent
    Close #1
    strContent() = Split(FileContent, vbCrLf)

    ' Here i will do some conditional replecments split text into an array by lines etc.

    'Polaczenie pliku
    FileContent = Join(strContent, vbCrLf)

    'Otworzenie txt w trybie zapisu
    Open FilePath For Output As TextFile

    'Zapisanie zmienionej zawartosci do pliku
    Print #TextFile, FileContent

    'Zakmniecie pliku
    Close TextFile

    MyTxtFile = Shell("C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe " & FilePath, 1)

    'etykieta wyjscia z programu
BeforeExit:
    'wyjscie z programu
    Exit Sub
    'etykieta radzenia sobie z bledami
ErrorHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    'skierowanie do wyjscia z programu
    Resume BeforeExit
    'koniec makra
End Sub
```

Comment: The process you've shown is feasible with simple WSH VBScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try one of the following:

1. Copy the code into VB.NET Windows Form and correct the errors as you go
2. Install VB6 and paste the code into a project (since VBA is VB6 code). Then attempt to open the VB6 project in VB.NET, at which point it'll perform an upgrade process for you

Good luck.

Comment: I don't believe Visual Studio has had the ability to upgrade VB 6 projects since about VS 2008.

Comment: You can not just open VB6 and past in VBA code.  There are several objects that won't exist. `ActiveWorkbook`  as an example from the above

Comment: Ok. I wilk try vb6. Ofc i will change active.workbook etc. Problem is i know some vba and i dont have time to get to know vb net.. :) I quess i will have to find the time to learn vb net. Thank You all!

Comment: That was a silly question when i am looking years back now :) but every right anserw should be upvoted and accepted - sorry for delay ! :D